# Google Play store app rejection due to policy violation

Tags: android, youtube, google-play, android-youtube-api

After app submission I am getting message that "My app submission was rejected for violating the Device and Network Abuse policy. Before submitting your app for another review, read through the policy and modify your app to make sure that it doesn't download, monetise or access YouTube videos in a way that violates the YouTube Terms of Service."

In that app I am just playing a youtube video with youtube video player. Suggest me that how to publish this app successfully.

Comment: Just read the rules and follow them, nothing special

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a programming problem

Answer (score 5):

I just solved this problem with Google and I'm going to tell my experience: In my case, from nowhere, I just received that my app was suspended and I have to read the 4.9 section of Google Play because that was what I violated. After asking for more information (because yes, Google love to make you read all of their websites), they told me that my problem was related with the Youtube API Service, so, I just went to the Youtube Politics in order to spend all morning reading.

After reading a few things that I might be ignoring (might, because I wasn't sure). (One of them was something about the Youtube Logo, in the [branding section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/branding-guidelines)).

Again, I resent an email to Google explaining that still, I didn't have enough info to know what was going on.

Finally, they sent me an email telling me that OK, rechecking again the app, they could set it again back in market with one condition: **remove the Youtube Service.**

Said and done. We did it and in one hour we had our app back in the store.... so... my conclusion:

First of all, you guys have to know that y app is in the Family Section, so I believe this was the thing: because is an app for Kids, maybe the Youtube service is not prepared for that, and I can imagine that a kid shouldn't go and navigate around other youtube videos. We thought about moving all our videos to Youtube Kids.. but not yet.

Second of all, I really think that the customer support of Google should improve in order to help developers. Suspending the app for almost a week is horrible for an enterprise, even more when you don't know what to do or solve. All this process is very annoying, so don't worry developer that you are reading this, be patient.

Answer (score 3):

Youtube related apps generally face rejections due to -
 Background play of youtube video is not allowed.

Detect back button activity and kill the youtube player which will stop the video. You will be able to publish the app after this fix.

Comment: the most accurate answer I saw about. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Youtube terms of service say that:

> II. Prohibitions.
>
> 10. Access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use of a YouTube player or other video player expressly
>     authorized by YouTube;

So the only way to make your app work and be on the Google Play is to contact Google or Youtube staff