# Google Play Store Removed AR App because of YouTube API

Tags: unity-game-engine, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

My AR application developed in Unity has been removed from the Google Play store after 6 months because it apparently violates the YouTube API. I do not use the YouTube API anywhere in my application, I am unsure where I have violated the terms of use.

Answer (score 1):

You may check on this [link](https://andrewrezk.com/how-i-restored-my-app-on-google-play-after-suspension/) for the possible reasons why your app has been removed. You might be also displaying banner ad while playing video. This violates their YouTube policy.

Here are some links which might help:

- [My app got rejected from google play due to some issue with network policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045639/my-app-got-rejected-from-google-play-due-to-some-issue-with-network-policy)
- [App removed from Google Play because of Youtube API problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915748/app-removed-from-google-play-because-of-youtube-api-problems)
- [How to fix the Device and Network abuse policy issue in Google play store app submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311473/how-to-fix-the-device-and-network-abuse-policy-issue-in-google-play-store-app-su)